# Multiple execution of same thread subroutine on commenting pthread_join for that thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to threading.
Here if I comment pthread_join( thread1, NULL) then in the output sometimes I get

```
    Thread2
    Thread1
    Thread1
```

I am not able to understand why Thread1 trace is coming twice and what is the exact functionality of pthread_join.

Also, please refer some tutorial on threading concepts for beginners.

```
    void *print_message_function( void *ptr );
    main()
    {
            pthread_t thread1, thread2;
            char *message1 = "Thread 1";
            char *message2 = "Thread 2";
            int  iret1, iret2;
            iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
            iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);
            pthread_join( thread1, NULL);

            pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

            printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
            printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);
            exit(0);
    }

    void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
    {
            char *message;
            message = (char *) ptr;
            printf("%s \n", message);
    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm that I can reproduce this on CentOS 6.2 using gcc 4.4.6. Nice puzzle! (+1)

Comment: My gcc version is 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
Thread model: posix

Comment: Can't reproduce with `gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) Thread model: posix`.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you build using the `-pthread` option instead of using `-lpthread`?  I'm wondering if the mysterious `-D_REENTRANT` option makes a difference in how the `printf()` calls are handled.  I wouldn't think so, but you never know...

Comment: Just tested, I can't reproduce with `-lpthread` (see my previous comment), but can with `-pthread`. Nice find @MichaelBurr

Comment: @Soohjun: that's exactly the opposite of what I would have expected (if it made a difference at all).

Comment: I was just about to suggest locking up the printf() with a mutex, just to see..

Comment: Are you getting a newline between the two prints of Thread 1? Because on my system they are printed on the same line.

Comment: @Tudor...ya I was getting the output on two different lines

Comment: are you getting anything else printed after this (like `Thread 1 returns: 0`) or just the output lines that you have shown?

Comment: @Gabriel....I am getting this after commenting the last two printf's

Comment: @KundanKumar I can't reproduce it on my system so I can't test any ideas that I have about why this is happening.  One thing you might want to try is changing `exit(0)` to `pthread_exit(0)`.  Also one guess I had about why this is happening is because you are sharing data through the stack, which might change state when the `main` thread exits.  But without being able to reproduce this myself I can't figure out if my guess is correct or not.

Comment: @Gabriel...have you tried after commenting last two printf statement ?

Comment: @KundanKumar, yes when I do that I only get `Thread2` printed.  I don't have the problem of `Thread1` printing twice, which is the interesting part of this question because that should not happen.

Comment: @Gabriel...actually that will be reproduced if you run the program several times....may be around 10-15

Comment: @Gabriel: regarding sharing data through the stack - I'm not sure I see what you're referring to. The data passed to the threads are pointers to string literals, which are statically allocated so have no ties to the lifetime of `main()` (other than the lifetime of the process as a whole).

Comment: @MichaelBurr that's a good point I did not think about the fact that the strings will be statically allocated.

Comment: The thread function does not return anything. The lack of return value in non-void function may cause strange behavior in some situations. Did you try to add `return SomeValue;` to  `print_message_function()`?

Comment: @Kundan: Is the problem solved or still facing the same thing? If not solved did you try out the answer i posted? Please share the result.. thanks

Comment: @happy2Help...on modifying the code in the way you suggested the output is proper and expected...still I just needed some explanation to my question ... i mean the nature of the output ..why thread1 was being printed twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting these results, first of all I would do the following:

1)         Instead of below lines,

```
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);

iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);
pthread_join( thread1, NULL);

pthread_join( thread2, NULL);
```

replace it with,

```
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);

pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

pthread_join( thread2, NULL);
```

and see what is the result.

2) Inside your thread function, you need to call pthread_exit("Exit"); This is a proper way to exit from the thread function. Do it at the end of function.

```
void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
        char *message;
        message = (char *) ptr;
        printf("%s \n", message);
        pthread_exit("Exit"); 
    }
```

If you are doing it this way, ideally you should not face any problem. In every case, i am assuming you are compiling your program using `gcc -D_REENTRANT -o threadex threadex.c -lpthread`

This is not the final solution. If it is going well, then we can proceed to next step of starting both the threads at a time.

Please share the feedback after incorporating these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the output buffer is not flushing correctly. I've encountered a very similar issue when doing multithreading and piping the output to a file--sometimes output would appear twice. Try adding this line to your main function:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This will force the output buffer to be flushed on each write.