# why does it print thrice when using pthreads?

Tags: c++, pthreads

Consider the following snippet of code. It would be sane to guess that it would print atmost two numbers to standard output. But on some runs I get the following:

```
user@homedesk:test~> ./test
140641008801600
140640992085760
140640992085760
```

Why is it printing out three numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>


static void* create_thread(void *ptr)
{
    std::cout << " " << pthread_self() << std::endl;
    while(1);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, create_thread, NULL);
    std::cout << pthread_self() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what system does it do this?  I can only get it to print twice.

Comment: your code has undefined behavior, you never join or detach your thread. your main thread terminates earlier than created thread.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the code.  Where is the leading space on the thread's output?

Comment: This is a linux system and I edited the output so that it shows up as code for SO.

Comment: @billz you seem to be right. After I add a pthread_join in the main function this behaviour does not repeat.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550662/pthread-one-printf-statement-get-printed-twice-in-child-thread  For some reason on Linux (maybe other systems?) an unjoined thread can cause the last line of output to be repeated when the process ends.  I think that's a bug in the runtime, but other people seem to be of the opinion that ending a process with an unjoined thread results in an undefined or unspecified behavior situation that permits this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of pthreads which are not joined is undefined. The inconsistency vanishes if you join pthreads at the end of the main function.