# A strange result in a simple pthread code

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* sayHello (void *x){
    printf ("Hello, this is %d\n", (int)pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main (){
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &sayHello, NULL);
    printf("HERE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling and running I saw 3 different types of outputs.

1. Only "Here" was printed.
2. "Here" and 1 'sayHello' message.
3. "Here" and 2 'sayHello' messages.

Of course I'm OK with the second option, but I don't understand why the 'sayHello' massege can be printed 0 or 2 times if I created only one thread?

Comment: I don't know why it would print twice, but unless pThreads work differently, you're not waiting for the thread to join, so there's the possibility that the program will end before `sayHello` is called, which would account for the first case.

Comment: the 'return NULL' in the thread function should be: '' pthread_exit(NULL)'

Comment: 1) the main() function should wait for the thread to exit, perhaps using 'pthread_join( thread );'  this will assure the printf() is fully executed in the thread.  2) the returned value(==0) from pthread_create() should be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For output 1:

your `main` function only create a pthread, and let it run without waiting for it to finish.

When your main function return, Operating system will collect back all the resources assigned to the pprocess. However the newly created pthread might have not run.

That is why you only got `HERE`.

### For output 2:

your newly created thread finished before `main` function return. Therefore you can see both the main thread, and the created thread's output.

### For output 3

This should be a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14697) in `glibc`. Please refer to [Unexpected output in a multithreaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211423/unexpected-output-in-a-multithreaded-program)  for details.

### To make the program always has the same output

[`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is needed after `pthread_create`

Comment: Thank you for the answers for outputs 1 and 2. About output 3: I just  run the program multiple times and saw that this option exists. I really don't have more information...

Comment: I Update the answer since output 3 seems to be a bug in glibc.

Comment: Besides joining the threads alternativly one could leave `main()` using `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: Another related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550662/pthread-one-printf-statement-get-printed-twice-in-child-thread

Answer (score 6):

You can't say when the thread starts to run, it might not start until 
*after* you return from `main` which means the process will end and the thread with it.

You have to wait for the thread to finish, with `pthread_join`, before leaving `main`.

The third case, with the message from the thread printed twice, might be because the thread executes, and the buffer is written to `stdout` as part of the end-of-line flush, but then the thread is preempted before the flush is finished, and then the process exist which means all file streams (like `stdout`) are flushed so the text is printed again.

Comment: I think the OP is tripping.

Comment: I understand what you said about the first option, but the third option is still unclear to me...

Comment: @Carcigenicate OP isn't. It's a known issue see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211423/unexpected-output-in-a-multithreaded-program) and this [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14697).

Comment: @BlueMoon I was actually just coming back to say "nvm". Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Joachim why would it be undefined? It's the same as any thread calling `exit()` anytime.

Comment: Well, since process termination is an OS action, it's defined by the OS action - all process threads get stopped, all user resources freed, all kernel process resouces freed, process no longer exists.  If there are unwanted consequences at user level, the overall design is inadequate since processes may get stopped at any time, eg. by 'kill -9', Task Manager or power fail.  'You have to wait for the thread to finish, with pthread_join, before leaving main' - no, you don't, not with any non-trivial OS.

Comment: Besides joining the threads alternativly one could leave `main()` using `pthread_exit()`.