# Buffering `printf` outputs between different threads in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, buffering

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t ntid;void
printids(const char *s) {
  printf("%s \n", s);
}

void *
thr_fn(void *arg)   {
  printids("new thread: ");
  return((void *)0);
}

int
main(void)  {
  pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);
  printids("main thread:");
}
```

I'm running it on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.5 .
Here is my compiling command

> gcc -ansi -g -std=c99 -Wall -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE  threadid.c -o threadid  -pthread -lrt -lbsd

Here is the output:

> main thread:
>     new thread:
>     new thread:

Why "new thread" has been printed twice?
I doubt this may related to buffering mechanism in Linux. But after I added `fflush(stdout)` and `fsync(1)` in the end of each function. The output is almost the same.

If you run the program several times. The output differs:

> main thread:
>   new thread:

or

> main thread:
>   new thread:
>   new thread:

Or

> main thread:

Comment: What do you mean with "almost the same"? If there are differences, what are they?

Comment: This doesn't compile. Please make it a [mcve]. I don't think the doubled output can be caused by the lines you provide here.

Comment: adding a declaration for `ntid` and a `pthread_join()` gives exactly the expected output, btw.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (after having added a `pthread_t ntid` definition).

Comment: Did you actually try the code you posted here (which is at least complete now after the edit)? It gives the expected output, nothing is printed twice. It **might** not print `new thread:` **at all** as you don't do a `pthread_join()`, so the program could end before the new thread had a chance to run. But it's impossible this is printed twice.

Comment: You can run it multiple times. @StephanLechner

Comment: Gave it about 20 tries; at least no double output of `new thread:`.

Comment: I can expect a scenario where __only__ main thread gets printed, because you don't wait for the created thread. But I cannot reproduce double new thread.

Comment: By the way, there's only one buffer *per process*. The worst that could happen is that the output from the main and child threads become intermingled, but you should not get duplication. Duplication similar to what you show can happen when creating a child *process* though, but should not happen with threads.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe you are referring to the buffer associated with `stdout` from the operating system, but the libc implementation could have a per thread output buffer.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya No I mean the C standard I/O buffering used by `printf`. And no matter if it's implemented using one buffer per process, or one per thread, this duplication should not happen. Especially if it's one buffer per thread.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do you think about the scenario I mentioned in my answer below? I agree the case I mentioned would be a bug in the implementation of libc, but could be possible.

Comment: Can you post the output from `ldd threadid`?  If you're linking in some library with a non-thread-safe `stdout` stream, that could explain your inconsistent results.

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6efff000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003f77c00000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003f77400000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003f76c00000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f76400000)
@AndrewHenle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most libc libraries do buffer the output as you mentioned. And at the end of the program (when the main thread exits), they flush all the buffers and exit.

There is a slight possibility that your new thread has flushed the output but before it could update the state of the buffer, the main program exited and the cleanup code flushed the same buffer again. Since these buffers are local to the thread I am sure they won't have concurrency mechanism. But because of this rare case it might get messed up.

You can try

```
err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);
printids("main thread:");
pthread_join(ntid, NULL);
```

At the end of the main function and check if the problem is solved.

This will cause your main function to wait till the new thread is finished (including the flushing operation it does).

Comment: Given Linux's conflation of threads and processes (they're similar, but different), I suspect that this is the cause of the trouble when the main thread exits without waiting for the child thread to complete.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I disagree. GLIBC does have internal locking for multithreading, as the various interfaces (including `fflush()`) are marked MT-Safe. I believe the underlying cause is the fact that `return` from `main()` in Linux immediately kills all threads (both that and `exit()` actually invoke the `exit_group()` syscall). Simply put, I don't believe the newly started thread(s) always get(s) to run before it is killed.

Comment: @NominalAnimal how can we explain the duplication? (if it indeed is happening, I cannot reproduce).

Comment: @NominalAnimal and I agree that the implementation of `fflush` must be having locks but on the side that it deals with the stdout fd. Are there locks for updating the per thread buffer states?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The locks are [per stream](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofflush.c;hb=HEAD), not per thread, and the final flush at end of process has an [explicit lock](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/genops.c;hb=HEAD). Unless the OP has a C library compiled for !_IO_MTSAFE_IO, or OP is using _unlocked() versions of the I/O functions, I don't see any way you could get a duplicate output using only one thread (in addition to the main one).

Answer (score 2):

Double output **is** possible on glibc-based linux systems due to a nasty bug in glibc: if the `FILE` lock is already held at the time `exit` tries to flush, the lock is simply ignored and the buffer access is performed with no synchronization. This would be a great test case to report to glibc to pressure them to fix it, if you can reproduce it reliably.

Comment: Looks like there are even more threading bugs in glibc's exit handling:  https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14333