# What happens when pthread_join is commented?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, pthread-join

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mythreads.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *
mythread(void *arg) {
    printf("%s\n", (char *) arg);
    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: main\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_t p1, p2;
    printf("main: begin\n");
    Pthread_create(&p1, NULL, mythread, "A");
    Pthread_create(&p2, NULL, mythread, "B");
    // join waits for the threads to finish
    //Pthread_join(p1, NULL); 
    //Pthread_join(p2, NULL); 
    printf("main: end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code from [Remzi](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) Chapter 27. Playing around, I'm curious to know why sometimes on run, I get A printed twice. I know why this is happening, because I haven't included the join statement. Why should skipping join cause this?

My output:

```
shubham@HP:~/OS/Code-Threads-Intro$ ./a.out 
main: begin
A
main: end
B
shubham@HP:~/OS/Code-Threads-Intro$ ./a.out 
main: begin
A
main: end
B
shubham@HP:~/OS/Code-Threads-Intro$ ./a.out 
main: begin
main: end
A
shubham@HP:~/OS/Code-Threads-Intro$ ./a.out 
main: begin
main: end
B
A
A
```

Comment: Please fix the compiler errors in your code and remove the dependency on a non-provided `"mythreads.h"` header.

Comment: Are the capitalized function names cover functions for the all lower-case versions of the function name except they do some sort of error handling and perhaps reporting?  As it stands, only someone intimately familiar with the `"mythreads.h"` header and the book/course materials can reliably help.  We can make (more or less well) educated guesses, but we don't like having to guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pthread: one printf statement get printed twice in child thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550662/pthread-one-printf-statement-get-printed-twice-in-child-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the call the `pthread_join()` should not cause "A" to be printed twice. (Barring a bug in the implementation.)

But since your `fprintf()` calls share the same `FILE *` structure, they may not be not multithread-safe.  How and why they could print "A" twice is dependent upon the implementation details of your system's `fprintf()` function.

Comment: Thank you for adding insight. But I dont think I clearly follow your answer. You say that its being printed twice due to implementation flaw of printf()?

Comment: Yes.  It's a bug:  https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14697  *This bug is due to intentional hackery in glibc to avoid hanging on exit() due to locks being held by other threads, under the wrong assumption that exit() "should" immediately exit in this case. There is no language in the standards to support what glibc is doing.* Also: *It seems that this bug can also result in more serious corruption such as duplicate output, even without any explicit file locking.*