# Why do I get these results in this small program with threads in C (LINUX)?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have this small program that I found in an exam subject of an OS course.

```
void * func (void * p) {
    int n = p;
    printf("%d \n",n);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    pthread_t t[3];
    for(i=0; i<3; i+=1)
        pthread_create(&t[i] ,NULL, func, (void*)i);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following results (with a new line after each digit):

> 1st run : 0 0
>   2nd run : 1 0 2 2
>   3rd run : 0 1 1

Why does it print 4 digits when I only create 3 threads. And how can it print duplicates?

The code is compiled with gcc in Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot of the terminal]

Comment: I've been experimenting with this program, and I cannot reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: i didn't get them in that exact order, most of the runs i didn't get any output(which is understandable, because the main process ends before the created threads are executed), sometimes i got 0, 0 1 , 0 2 ,2 0 (which are also expected). But I can't see how i could get the above outputs. I will upload a screen shot of the terminal to prove it.

Comment: Maybe the parent thread terminates before the children?

Comment: Please also include the exact command line you give to your compiler when building the code.

Comment: Since you haven't *joined* with main thread, it's expected to get less than 3 values printed for some runs when main threads exits before others. But I don't know how this will ever print 4 values in any run.

Comment: gcc -Wall -o 1 1.c -lpthread

Comment: This question has been asked several times, but never with an answer that I think is satisfactory. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10322175/12711 and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13550662/12711 - Maybe someone will give a good answer this time...

Comment: `$ cat out.txt |  sort -n | tail` yields these:
`0210
210
210
210
210
210
210
210
1002
01012`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not join your threads before exiting main().  Add the following into `main()`:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i+=1)
    pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
```

Not joining the threads leads to *undefined behavior* when the threads continue to execute while the program is exiting.  Undefined behavior is free to do anything, including printing duplicates.

Think of it this way, the `void*` that is passed to the thread is stored somewhere, and once you prematurely exit main you *could be* destructing the data to pass to the thread, at which point it can take on any value (including duplicate ones).  But this isn't even worth trying to explain since it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for *Not joining the threads leads to undefined behavior when your `pthread_t`s are destructed while the thread they're associated with runs in the background.*?

Comment: Well, undefined behavior often *can* be explained, knowing what's going on under the hood (i.e. going besides the specs and looking at the implementation). The problem here is that it's particularly complicated to dissect the problem, since the behavior is substantially non-deterministic.

Comment: @Matteo Removed the *unexplainable* part to avoid confusion.

Comment: @NPE I removed that bit since technically `pthread_t` is just an identifier, and I won't go into the details of launching a thread.

Answer (score 2):

`return` from the `main` function is equivalent to a call to `exit` and terminates the whole process. So its more or less random which output makes it through to your screen. You should do one of the following

- join all threads that you create
- call `pthread_exit` at the end of `main` instead of calling `exit` or using `return`

Comment: in the exam, this code is given , and it asks which of the following will print : 
(_)(_)(_)0 0. ALWAYS/SOMETIMES/NEVER
(_)(_)(_)Nothing.  ALWAYS/SOMETIMES/NEVER
(_)(_)(_)2 0 0 ALWAYS/SOMETIMES/NEVER
(_)(_)(_)0 1 2 ALWAYS/SOMETIMES/NEVER
(_)(_)(_)2 0 . ALWAYS/SOMETIMES/NEVER
and i would have answered that i could never output 0 0 (but after i ran the code i was proven wrong)

Comment: @user2016514, with the answers you should be able to find that out.

Comment: Since you got into UB, the correct reply is "sometimes" for every one. Actually, running the executable in a loop it managed to produce `0�:զ����������%զ�@������`զ�� �����������:զ���������'զ�����`զ�`զ�`զ�`զ��!զ��"զ�`#զ��桦�`�Ԧ�`����wg70 ` (and other random garbage as well).